# Log into gmail using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log into gmail using Selenium. In the new gmail log in, first you type your email id and then a next page comes where you type your password. URL of email page and password page, both are different. So, when I am passing the password URL in `driver.get` it is reloading the page and it redirects to email page if you refresh the URL without entering password. Because of this, it is missing the password field selector. `current_url` is still the previous url, i.e, url of email page. This is my code. I am using chrome driver and python 2.X

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = "/Documents/chromedriver" # Path to chrome-driver
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

# Email insert 

driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")  #URL of email page
username = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
username.send_keys("myemail")
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()


# Password Insert 

driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")  # URL of password page
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("mypassword")
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()

#driver.quit()
```

Comment: You could try not doing the second `driver.get`. If the next field comes up asynchronously, it may not be needed.

Comment: I tried it, but it was missing the password selector every time.

Comment: You may need to add a WebDriver wait or sleep to wait for the new field to appear.

Comment: Google does this on purpose to make it difficult. +1 for waiting on the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When we work with **`Selenium 3.4.3`**, **`geckodriver v0.17.0`** and **`Mozilla Firefox 53.0`** using **`Python 3.6.1`**, we can use either of the locators **`xpath`** or **`css_selector`** to log into our respective Gmail accounts through **`Gmail's signin module v2`**.

---

### Using XPATH :

Here is the sample code to log into Gmail using `xpath`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
email_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
email_phone.send_keys("your_emailid_phone")
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"))
)
password.send_keys("your_password")
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
```

---

### Using CSS_SELECTOR:

Here is the sample code to log into Gmail using `css_selector`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
email_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#identifierId")
email_phone.send_keys("your_emailid_phone")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ZFr60d.CeoRYc").click()
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='whsOnd zHQkBf'][type='password']"))
)
password.send_keys("your_password")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ZFr60d.CeoRYc").click()
```

Comment: have you had trouble recently signing into google with selenium? if so how did you work around this. it looks like they dont allow testing or browser automation software to sign in

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" 
   jsname="YPqjbf"  
   autocomplete="current-password"  
   spellcheck="false"  
   tabindex="0"  
   aria-label="Enter your password"  
   name="password"  
   autocapitalize="off"  
   autocorrect="off"  
   dir="ltr"  
   data-initial-dir="ltr"  
   data-initial-value=""  
   badinput="false"  
   type="password">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).