# Google login does not working in the selenium test after upgrading Chrome to version 65

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After upgrading to version 65 of Chrome, the selenium test in python will not redirect you when you log in to Google.

The part of the scenario in which the error occurs is that after entering the Google login window, enter the login and enter the password, but after entering the password and accepting it, I am not redirected back to the website. The Google login window is suspended.

Installing the latest chromedriver does not solve the problem.
Works on the Chrome 64 version.

Comment: It's not recommended or supported. Cf. https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/worst.html#gmail_email_and_facebook_logins

Comment: How I can login with gmail using API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log into gmail using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856887/log-into-gmail-using-selenium-in-python)