# How to select the Email or Phone field within Google Login Page with Selenium and xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, google-home

I am on this page:  [Google Drive Login](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=wise&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Den&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=web&utm_content=gotodrive&usp=gtd&ltmpl=drive&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)
Wanting to select this input field:
[image: The input field in question]

When I use the xpath of the input field:

```
//*[@id="identifierId"]
```

or

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input
```

I get nada.

Normally this happens when an element is nested within an iframe but not in this case.
Or at least I couldn't find the iframe in question. Please help me understand why.

Comment: what is the  error

Comment: The usual `nosuchelementexception`.
I normally get them when the element is inside an iframe.

Comment: Did you add sleep ?

Comment: Yes, of course. :) Are you saying it's working for you right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Email or Phone* field while accessing *Google Drive* login page is no different from the *Email or Phone* field during *GMail* login.

To send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `id`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys("AturSams")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#identifierId").send_keys("AturSams")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']").send_keys("AturSams")
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "identifierId"))).send_keys("AturSams")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#identifierId"))).send_keys("AturSams")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='identifierId']"))).send_keys("AturSams")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Gmail login using selenium webdriver in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455269/gmail-login-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java/44456085#44456085)
- [Log into gmail using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856887/log-into-gmail-using-selenium-in-python/44858643#44858643)
- [Selenium test scripts to login into google account through new ajax login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953043/selenium-test-scripts-to-login-into-google-account-through-new-ajax-login-form/45953576#45953576)

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=wise&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Den&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=web&utm_content=gotodrive&usp=gtd&ltmpl=drive&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(7)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]")
search_bar.send_keys("some text")

time.sleep(7000)
driver.close()
```

its working as it is

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Strange :D I did the exact same thing.

Comment: @AturSams The unreliable `time.sleep()` does have some impact on the element rendering within the HTML. Hence the difference which you can avoid using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)

Comment: Never use time.slewp always buse explicit wait